# SharePoint Developement | Necessary to open visual studio with "Run as Administrator"?

Tags: visual-studio, administration

I have created new environment for SharePoint development, added developers as domain user in AD.
In my comapny there is a policy that no one has administrative prevelages.
When I start Visual studio to develope SharePoint solution, it asks for administrative prevelages but my policy dosn't allow me to give administrator prevelages to any of the developer.
Is there any way to develope SharePoint solution in Visual Studio without using administrator prevelages ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you're going to deploy the wsp from vs than you need to open it as administrator because it need the system account. So you won't be able to debug 
While if you want to just build or publish the solution than its not needed.

Comment: Thank you Nitish for comment.
My question was is there any other way for that ? always I want to deploy the solution.

Comment: You won't be able to do that what I think.